# Create one 16-bit vector from two 8-bit vectors

Tags: vector, concatenation, vhdl

I want to create one 16-bit-vector from two 8-bit-vectors but have errors like below. How to solve it?

```
LIBRARY ieee;  
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;  

ENTITY Binary2Gray IS  
-- Declarations  
port(data : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);  
data_out : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);  
data1 : inout std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);  
data2 : inout std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);  
CLK_I : in std_logic;  
y1 : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   
y2 : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  
op : out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0)  
);  
END Binary2Gray ;  

-----------------------------
ARCHITECTURE rtl OF Binary2Gray IS  

signal op : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);  

begin  
    process(CLK_I)  
BEGIN  
data_out(3) <=data(3);  
data_out(2) <=data(3) xor data (2);  
data_out(1) <=data(2) xor data (1);  
data_out(0) <=data(1) xor data (0);  
label_1: for data_out in 0 to 3 loop  
    if(data_out = 0 ) then  
 data1(0) <=data(1) xor data (0);  
 elsif (data_out = 1 ) then  
    data1(1) <=data(2) xor data (1);  
elsif (data_out = 2 ) then  
    data2(0) <=data(3) xor data (2);  
else  
    data2(1) <=data(3);  
end if;  
end loop label_1;  
end process;  
with data1 select y1 <=  
"00110011" when "00",  
"00111101" when "01",  
"11010011" when "10",  
"11011101" when others;  
with data2 select y2 <=  
"00110011" when "00",  
"00111101" when "01",  
"11010011" when "10",  
"11011101" when others;  
op <= y1 & y2 ;  
 END rtl;
```

Errors:

```
# Error: ELAB1_0008: QAM.vhd : (56, 8): Cannot read output : "y1".  
# Error: ELAB1_0008: QAM.vhd : (56, 8): Cannot read output : "y2".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VHDL-2002 (and earlier) it is not allowed to read an output port like `y1`
and `y2`, hence the error.

Possible fixes are any of:

- declared `y1` and `y2` as `buffer` ports
- create intermediate signals `y1_sig` and `y2_sig` with the values and
  assign these to `y1`, `y2`, and `op`
- use VHDL-2008 if possible in the tool chain.

Note that `op` should not be declared as signal when an output port.  Note
also that the process does probably not work as expected, since it is not a
clocked process due to missing `if rising_edge(CLK_I) then` statement, nor a combinatorial
process due to missing `data` in sensitivity list.

Comment: thank you morten i changed  y1 and y2 to buffers and removed signal in op so it worked